# No method SignInProcedure with correct signature found on type

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous, exception

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 27:57. No method
>   SignInProcedure with correct signature found on type
>   HabitRON.Views.LoginPage'

I tried to make the `SignInProcedure` `async` method to return `void` instead of `Task` type.
I have set the `Linker Options` to `Sdk` and `User Assemblies`.

This problem started when I added a `RestService` `async` method:

```
var result = await App.RestService.Login(user);

async void SignInProcedureAsync (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    User user = new User(Entry_Username.Text,Entry_Password.Text);

    //user.UserName = Lbl_Username.Text;

    if (user.CheckInformation())
    {
        DisplayAlert("Login", "Login sucess!","OK");

        var result = await App.RestService.Login(user);
        if (result .access_token != null)
        {
            App.UserDatabase.UpdateUser(user);
        }                
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("Login", "Login failure! Insert a Username and a Password", "OK");
    }
}
```

Any ideas? 
Before this the login page appeared normally.

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand the question, but your error message says something is wrong with **SignInProcedure**, but your piece of code is about SignInProcedure**Async**. Don't you have a piece of code trying to call a method that does not exist ?

Answer (score 0):

If using async void , you should not use UI method in this thread.Have a try with **[Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms)** :

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  DisplayAlert("Login", "Login sucess!","OK");
});
```